# Range slider appears to 'skip' values when using in anger

Tags: javascript, html, input, range

I am having an issue with the standard html5 range slider when calling the input event in Javascript. When using the slider in anger it appears to skip values. Because I am using this as zoom functionality alongside cropper.j this is giving me quite a headache as it is not honouring the values and stepping over steps of the slide process.

I have read extensively online and cannot seem to come by a solution for this. Is this a browser bug or is there an attribute I am missing?

```
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" step="10" class="crop__controls--slider" id="crop__controls--slider" />
```

...and the Javascript for this;

```
var event = (isIE()) ? 'change' : 'input'; //ie11 does not support input event
  slider.off(event).on(event, function(e) {
    var sliderValue = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
    var type;
    if (sliderValue > currentZoomSetting) {
      type = 'in';
    } else {
      type = 'out';
    }
    zoom(type);
    currentZoomSetting = sliderValue;
  });
```

Help on this would be much appreciated.

See below a fiddle that if, used excessively, shows that values are skipped using the input event.

```js
var slider = document.getElementById('slider');
slider.addEventListener('input', sliderChange);

function sliderChange() {
  console.log(this.value);
}
```

```html
 <input id="slider" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" step="10" />
```

Comment: By 'skip' do you mean that it increments/decrements in steps of 10? That would be due to the `step="10"` property of the input

Comment: No, it increments in steps of 10. That is what I want it to do. If you use the slider fast (excessively) it skips through points of the slide. You can test it in the fiddle above.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, is there any way I can control the fast behaviors of the mouse and make sure no matter what it always step=1?